# Atualizar options de um select que é construído pelo banco de dados sem atualizar a página

Tags: php, javascript, html

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, tenho um select que suas options são construídas a partir dos dados no banco:

```html
<select id="cCoo" name="tCoo">
  <option style="font-style: italic" id="dsb" disabled elected>Selecione...</option>
  <?php
                include('../configBD.php');
                $sql = "select * from coordenador";
                $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
                while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    $codigo = $dados['idCoo'];
                    $nome = $dados ['tNomCoo'];
                    echo "<option value='$codigo'>$nome</option>";
                }
                ?>
</select>
```

A inserção de novos dados é feito a partir de um botão na mesma página que abre uma pop-up e o usuário pode cadastrar um novo coordenador como no exemplo abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vamos supor que o usuário cadastre um novo coordenador, feche a página de cadastro e precise selecionar aquele coordenador que ele acabara de inserir no banco. O problema é exatamente este... Para refreshar as options coloquei um botão de refresh ali, e preciso de uma função que faça o refresh das options, ou seja, sem que o usuário precise atualizar toda a página fazendo com que o que ele havia preenchido se perca.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse botão de refresh roda alguma função em javascript? Se sim, vc pode rodar essa função via `opener`. Dá uma olhada no final dessa página: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Na verdade esse botão de refresh é só um link com um icone de refresh, ele não tem função alguma pré-estabelecida, é exatamente nele que quero colocar uma função para recarregar os dados vindo do banco nas options.

Comment: Uma ideia seria vc construir esse `select` via *ajax* e chamar essa função *após adicionar nova opção* na janelinha extra. Daí vc vai chamar a página principal via `javascript` como mencionado no comentário anterior: `janelinhaExtra.opener.construirSelect()`;

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, depois do usuário colocar os dados, nome, numero, etc, etc,  no momento em que ele apertar o botão enviar lá da janelinha (pop-up) além de inserir os dados no banco eu faço uma função para atualizar a página principal inteira? Mas ai não cairia naquela situação imposta, na qual se a página toda for atualizada tudo que o usuário já inseriu no formulário será resetado. Eu preciso que ao inserir um novo dado somente as options sejam atualizadas, ou pode ser usando aquele botão de refresh mesmo, não tem problema.